# Using animation set, animation does not happen sequentially

Tags: android, animation, text, refresh, android-animation

I am trying to set blink animation on two words so that they blink one after the other, but what ever I do only 2nd word is displayed, can any one provide me method for doing the same, I am working with API level 10 so, cannot use "Animatorset".

```
            AnimationSet set = new AnimationSet( true );
             Animation blink = new AlphaAnimation(1, 0 );
             blink.setDuration(duration);
             blink.setFillAfter(true);
             set.addAnimation( blink );
             txtvw.setText("FIRST");
             txtvw.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
             txtvw.setAnimation(blink);




            AnimationSet set2 = new AnimationSet( true );
              Animation blink2 = new AlphaAnimation(1, 0 );
              blink2.setDuration(duration);
              blink2.setFillAfter(true);
              set2.addAnimation( blink );
             txtvw.setText("SECOND");
             txtvw.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
             txtvw.setAnimation(blink2);
```

Answer (score 0):

if your code is like this, your text "first" gets replaced by text "Second" immediately. And the animation is shown. This animation gives an illusion that only second is blinking. Your text first is being set for microseconds but it immediately gets replaced by second.

If you want to show both the texts, you may need to use `Thread`

Answer (score 0):

1. Using two animation sets for the same animations (that is, "blinking animation") is an overkill. You may just repeat your animation 2 times. Use `setRepeatCount(int)` in conjunction with `setRepeatMode(int)` to achieve this.
2. If you insist on using the code you have provided in your post, you will need to specify animation offset. Animation offset indicates "how much time should animation wait before start". For example, if you have `Animation` **a** and **b**, and want **b** happen after **a**, you might use the code:

`b.setStartOffset(a.getDuration());`

Then **b** animation will happen just after **a** has finished.